# setting delay on displaying element

Tags: html, css, transition

how can i set delay on displaying sth when i hover sth else?
i would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    

<div class="sthelse"> sthelse </div>
<div class="sth">sth</div>

</body>
</html>

.sth{
    display: none;
}
.sthelse:hover + .sth{
    display: block;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

Comment: you cannot transition/animate the `display` property with CSS - use `opacity` along with `visibility` or use JavaScript to achieve the same effect

Comment: thanks ,it worked along with visibility

Answer (score 0):

To add a transition that makes something appear, you will need to add a transition to the opacity property. Set the opacity to 0, and on hover, set it to 1 with a transition of 2 seconds:

```css
.sth {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 2s;
}
.sthelse:hover + .sth {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 2s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="sthelse"> sthelse </div>
    <div class="sth">sth</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In as much as this can be achieved with raw css. It can be achieved easily using jQuery `fadeIn`

Will use a snippet to demonstrate

```css
.sth{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

<div class="sthelse"> sthelse </div>
<div class="sth">sth</div>

<script>
$('.sthelse').hover(function() {
  $('.sth').stop().fadeIn(2000); 
},
function() {
 $('.sth').stop().fadeOut(2000);
})

</script>

</body>
</html>
```